# Как сделать чтобы изменялось значение переменной PyQT5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

Хочу чтобы при нажатии **`кнопки 3`**, цифра **3** появлялась на дисплее, затем при нажатии кнопки **`**`**, и последующем нажатии, например **`кнопки 2`**, она также появлялась на дисплее вместо **3**.

После этого при нажатии `=` оно все считалось, дисплей очищался и на него выводился результат.

Как делать это в командной строке я знаю, а вот с интерфейсом pyqt5 не знаю. 
Помогите пожалуйста.

Вот код программы:

```py
import os
import time
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import design

print('Калькулятор квадратных уравнений PyQuadCalc Beta запущен!')
print('<TechUP Copyrighted>')
run = 1
class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        # Это здесь нужно для доступа к переменным, методам
        # и т.д. в файле design.py
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  # Это нужно для инициализации нашего дизайна
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
    window = ExampleApp()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
    window.show()  # Показываем окно
    app.exec_()  # и запускаем приложение
if __name__ == '__main__':  # Если мы запускаем файл напрямую, а не импортируем
    main()  # то запускаем функцию main()
while run==1:
    mode = input('Выберите режим(1 - обычный калькулькулятор, 2 - калькулятор квадратных уравнений): ')
    while run==1:
        try:
            mode = int(mode)
        except:
            os.system('cls')
            print('Калькулятор квадратных уравнений PyQuadCalc Beta работает!')
            print('Вы ввели неправильное значение!')
            break
        if mode<1:
            os.system('cls')
            print('Калькулятор квадратных уравнений PyQuadCalc Beta работает!')
            print('Вы ввели неправильное значение!')
            break
        elif mode>2:
            os.system('cls')
            print('Калькулятор квадратных уравнений PyQuadCalc Beta работает!')
            print('Вы ввели неправильное значение!')
            break
        if mode==1:
            os.system('cls')
            print('Калькулятор квадратных уравнений PyQuadCalc Beta работает!')
            print('')
            print('Вы находитесь в режиме 1!')
            print('Введите exit чтобы выйти из режима')
            a = input('Введите значение a: ')
            try:
                a = int(a)
            except:
                print("Вы ввели неправильное значение!")
                break
            if a=='exit':
                break
            b = input('Введите значение b: ')
            try:
                b = int(b)
            except:
                print("Вы ввели неправильное значение!")
                break
            if b=='exit':
                break
            deistvie = input('Выберите действие( +, -, *, /, **(возвезти в степень) ): ')
            try:
                deistvie = str(deistvie)
            except:
                print('Вы ввели неправильное значение!')
                break
            if deistvie=='exit':
                break
            if deistvie=='+':
                result = int(a) + int(b)
                print('Результат: ' + str(result))
            if deistvie=='-':
                result = int(a) - int(b)
                print('Результат: ' + str(result))
            if deistvie=='*':
                result = int(a) * int(b)
                print('Результат: ' + str(result))
            if deistvie=='/':
                result = int(a) / int(b)
                print('Результат: ' + str(result))
            if deistvie=='**':
                result = int(a) ** int(b)
                print('Результат: ' + str(result))
        if mode==2:
            os.system('cls')
            print('Калькулятор квадратных уравнений PyQuadCalc Beta работает!')
            print('')
            print('Вы находитесь в режиме 2!')
            print('Введите exit чтобы выйти из режима')
            a = input('Введите значение a: ')
            if a=='exit':
                break
                os.system('cls')
            b = input('Введите значение b: ')
            if b=='exit':
                break
                os.system('cls')
            c = input('Введите значение c: ')
            if c=='exit':
                break
                os.system('cls')
            if int(a)==0:
                print('Вы ввели неправильное значение!')
            elif int(b)==0:
                print('Вы ввели неправильное значение!')
            elif int(c)==0:
                print('Вы ввели неправильное значение!')
            else:
                d = (((int(b))**2)-(4*(int(a))*(int(c))))
                print('Дескримминант равен: ' + str(d))
                if int(d)<0:
                    print('Нет корней!')
                elif int(d)==0:
                    x1 = ((-(int(b)))+(int(d)**.5))/(2*(int(a)))
                    print('Корни равны: ' + str(x1))
                else:
                    x1 = ((-(int(b)))+(int(d)**.5))/(2*(int(a)))
                    x2 = ((-(int(b)))-(int(d)**.5))/(2*(int(a)))
                    print('1 корень равен: ' + str(x1))
                    print('2 корень равен: ' + str(x2))
        print('Готово!')
        input('Для продолжение нажмите Enter!')
```

Вот код интерфейса:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 350)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 350))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 350))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 120, 70, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 120, 70, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 120, 70, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_9.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 180, 70, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 180, 70, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 180, 70, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 240, 70, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 240, 70, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 240, 70, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_1.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_1.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_1.setObjectName("pushButton_1")
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 160, 70, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_10.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 120, 70, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_11.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
        self.pushButton_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 200, 70, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_12.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_12.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_12.setObjectName("pushButton_12")
        self.pushButton_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 300, 70, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_13.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_13.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_13.setObjectName("pushButton_13")
        self.pushButton_14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 300, 70, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_14.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_14.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_14.setObjectName("pushButton_14")
        self.pushButton_15 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 300, 70, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_15.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_15.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_15.setObjectName("pushButton_15")
        self.pushButton_16 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_16.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 240, 70, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_16.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_16.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_16.setObjectName("pushButton_16")
        self.lcdNumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 271, 101))
        self.lcdNumber.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.lcdNumber.setSmallDecimalPoint(False)
        self.lcdNumber.setDigitCount(7)
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName("lcdNumber")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "/"))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "*"))
        self.pushButton_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "**"))
        self.pushButton_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))
        self.pushButton_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))
        self.pushButton_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))
        self.pushButton_16.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "="))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задачу, которую вы хотите сделать, я увидел так:

```
import sys
import operator                                                      # +++ !!!
#import os
#import time
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

#import design
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(300, 350)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(MainWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        MainWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 350))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 350))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_7 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_7.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 120, 70, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_7.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_7.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_7.setObjectName("pushButton_7")
        self.pushButton_8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_8.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 120, 70, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_8.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_8.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_8.setObjectName("pushButton_8")
        self.pushButton_9 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_9.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 120, 70, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_9.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_9.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_9.setObjectName("pushButton_9")
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 180, 70, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_5.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.pushButton_6 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_6.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 180, 70, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_6.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_6.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_6.setObjectName("pushButton_6")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 180, 70, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_4.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_4.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 240, 70, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_2.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 240, 70, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_3.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 240, 70, 60))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_1.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_1.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_1.setObjectName("pushButton_1")
        self.pushButton_10 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_10.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 160, 70, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_10.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_10.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_10.setObjectName("pushButton_10")
        self.pushButton_11 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 120, 70, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_11.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_11.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_11.setObjectName("pushButton_11")
        self.pushButton_12 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 200, 70, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_12.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_12.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_12.setObjectName("pushButton_12")
        self.pushButton_13 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 300, 70, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_13.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_13.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_13.setObjectName("pushButton_13")
        self.pushButton_14 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 300, 70, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_14.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_14.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_14.setObjectName("pushButton_14")
        self.pushButton_0 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 300, 70, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_0.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_0.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_0.setObjectName("pushButton_0")
        self.pushButton_15 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_15.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 240, 70, 100))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Berlin Sans FB")
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.pushButton_15.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_15.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.pushButton_15.setObjectName("pushButton_15")

        self.lcdNumber = QtWidgets.QLCDNumber(self.centralwidget)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 271, 101))
        self.lcdNumber.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border: 1px solid silver;")
        self.lcdNumber.setSmallDecimalPoint(False)
        self.lcdNumber.setDigitCount(7)
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName("lcdNumber")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "7"))
        self.pushButton_8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "8"))
        self.pushButton_9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "9"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.pushButton_6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.pushButton_1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.pushButton_10.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "/"))
        self.pushButton_11.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "*"))
        self.pushButton_12.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "**"))
        self.pushButton_13.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "-"))
        self.pushButton_14.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "+"))
        self.pushButton_0.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "0"))           # pushButton_0
        self.pushButton_15.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "="))          # pushButton_15


# состояниe
READY = 0
INPUT = 1


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)  

        for n in range(0, 10):
            getattr(self, 'pushButton_%s' % n).pressed.connect(lambda v=n: self.input_number(v))

        # Setup operations.
        self.pushButton_14.pressed.connect(lambda: self.operation(operator.add))
        self.pushButton_13.pressed.connect(lambda: self.operation(operator.sub))
        self.pushButton_11.pressed.connect(lambda: self.operation(operator.mul))
        self.pushButton_10.pressed.connect(lambda: self.operation(operator.truediv))    
        self.pushButton_12.pressed.connect(lambda: self.operation(operator.pow))        
        self.pushButton_15.pressed.connect(self.equals)

        self.memory = 0
        self.reset()

    def display(self):
        """ дисплей  """
        self.lcdNumber.display(self.stack[-1])

    def reset(self):
        """ Сброс """
        self.state = READY
        self.stack = [0]
        self.last_operation = None
        self.current_op = None
        self.display()

    def input_number(self, v):
        if self.state == READY:
            self.state = INPUT
            self.stack[-1] = v
        else:
            self.stack[-1] = self.stack[-1] * 10 + v
        self.display()

    def operation(self, op):
        if self.current_op:            
            self.equals()
        if op == operator.add or op == operator.sub:
            self.stack.append(0)
        elif op == operator.mul or op == operator.truediv or op == operator.pow:   # ???
            self.stack.append(1)
        self.state = READY
        self.current_op = op

    def equals(self):
        # Поддержка, чтобы '=' повторить предыдущую операцию         
        # если не было добавлено никаких дополнительных данных.
        if self.state == READY and self.last_operation:
            s, self.current_op = self.last_operation
            self.stack.append(s)
        if self.current_op:
            self.last_operation = self.stack[-1], self.current_op
            try:
                self.stack = [self.current_op(*self.stack)]
            except Exception:
                self.lcdNumber.display('Err')
                self.stack = [0]
            else:
                self.current_op = None
                self.state = READY
                self.display()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  
    window = ExampleApp()                
    window.show()                         
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

При помощи connect (Сигнально-слотового соединения).

Например, для любой кнопки берем сигнал clicked и соединяем его со слотом buttonClicked (можете назвать этот метод-слот по-другому, если пожелаете):

```
self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
...
self.pushButton_11.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)
```

Далее, определяем данный слот

```
class Ui_MainWindow:
    ...
    def buttonClicked(self):

        # Нажата кнопка?
        # метод self.sender() позволяет получить объект, отправивший сигнал
        if isinstance(self.sender(), QPushButton):
            button = self.sender()
            # Берем значение из кнопки
            buttonText = button.text()

            # Выводим текст кнопки
            self.lcdNumber.display(buttonText)

            ...
```